# Probability computation of normal distribution with offset

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

If given:

- an arbitrary value $c>0$
- a value $b$ drawn uniformly at random between 0 and *w* (with $w>0$)
- and another value z drawn from the standard normal distribution

What would be the probability that $b+c*z < w$ ?

I know the probability of b being smaller than a given value $r$ is $\int_{0}^{r} \frac{1}{w}$ (so just $\frac{r}{w}$)

The probability of $c*z < w$ is $ \int_{t=0}^{w/c}f_p(t) $ with $f_p$ the probability density function of the standard normal distribution.

But I'm struggling on how to put the two together.

EDIT:

we have $g(x)=1/W$ the probability density function of b.

So using convolution:
$\int_{0}^{w}f_p(t)*g(w-t) = \int_{0}^{w}f_p(t)*(1-\frac{t}{w})$

Comment: the result depends on the dependence between $b$ and $z$ - if they are independent you can look into convolutions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions) or using moment generating or characteristic functions. Specifically this post http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/952752/verification-of-convolution-between-gaussian-and-uniform-distributions should be interesting for you.

Comment: Thanks, convolution was what I was looking for.

Comment: the math stackexchange post treats exactly what you are looking for. have fun.